# Installing qutip package in python3.7 gives errors

Tags: linux-mint, python3, pip

I'm running Linux Mint 19.1 with Python 3.7.3 and am trying to install the qutip package. I've got the following installed so the dependencies should be fulfilled:

```
NumPy-1.16.4
SciPy-1.3.0
Maplotlib-3.1.0
Cython-0.29.10
GCC-8.0.1
```

I am not sure about the `Python Header` dependency but I ran

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

without errors as it was the only thing I could find when googling it.
When I try to install `qutip` using `pip` I get `error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'` twice, `Failed building wheel for py-postgresql` and `Failed to build qubit py-postgresql` after which it says the install was successful, see full print fro terminal:

```
$ python3.7 -m pip install qubit
Collecting qubit
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/fb/b9f75dba12698a1c394d9732d6d05008cc8a4d1d4854fc7201792e908626/qubit-0.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting Flask==0.11.1 (from qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/2b/01f5ed23a78391f6e3e73075973da0ecb467c831376a0b09c0ec5afd7977/Flask-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting py-postgresql==1.1.0 (from qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/cf/43d0287866f30f8b6f10ece19568fcda5477346c0f63bf5e9fb5c5eef121/py-postgresql-1.1.0.zip
Collecting pytest==3.0.3 (from qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/e9/bf75a9a91c4a545bad262937d1defa90d95ac912118a706406e21aef889a/pytest-3.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click>=2.0 (from Flask==0.11.1->qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/37/45185cb5abbc30d7257104c434fe0b07e5a195a6847506c074527aa599ec/Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from Flask==0.11.1->qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/e7/fd8b501e7a6dfe492a433deb7b9d833d39ca74916fa8bc63dd1a4947a671/Jinja2-2.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from Flask==0.11.1->qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/57/92a497e38161ce40606c27a86759c6b92dd34fcdb33f64171ec559257c02/Werkzeug-0.15.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from Flask==0.11.1->qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ae/44b03b253d6fade317f32c24d100b3b35c2239807046a4c953c7b89fa49e/itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting py>=1.4.29 (from pytest==3.0.3->qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/bc/394ad449851729244a97857ee14d7cba61ddb268dce3db538ba2f2ba1f0f/py-1.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask==0.11.1->qubit)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/7b/ff284bd8c80654e471b769062a9b43cc5d03e7a615048d96f4619df8d420/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: qubit, py-postgresql
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for qubit ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-bohuey6f/qubit/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpy8xqxz6ipip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for qubit
  Running setup.py clean for qubit
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for py-postgresql ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-bohuey6f/py-postgresql/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpl3nlfezopip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for py-postgresql
  Running setup.py clean for py-postgresql
Failed to build qubit py-postgresql
Installing collected packages: click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, Flask, py-postgresql, py, pytest, qubit
  Running setup.py install for py-postgresql ... done
  Running setup.py install for qubit ... done
Successfully installed Flask-0.11.1 Jinja2-2.10.1 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-0.15.4 click-7.0 itsdangerous-1.1.0 py-1.8.0 py-postgresql-1.1.0 pytest-3.0.3 qubit-0.0.1
In ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

I can then see two directories called `qutip` and `qutip-4.3.1-py3.7.egg-info` in `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` but if I run `python3.7` and try to `import qutip` an `ImportError` for something called `IndexMixin`, a `ModuleNotFoundError` for `apt_pkg`, see full printout.

```
$ python3.7
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 19:16:38) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import qutip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qutip/__init__.py", line 171, in <module>
    from qutip.qobj import *
  File "/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qutip/qobj.py", line 60, in <module>
    from qutip.fastsparse import fast_csr_matrix, fast_identity
  File "/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qutip/fastsparse.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.sputils import (upcast, upcast_char, to_native, isdense, isshape,
ImportError: cannot import name 'IndexMixin' from 'scipy.sparse.sputils' (/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qutip/__init__.py", line 171, in <module>
    from qutip.qobj import *
  File "/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qutip/qobj.py", line 60, in <module>
    from qutip.fastsparse import fast_csr_matrix, fast_identity
  File "/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qutip/fastsparse.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.sputils import (upcast, upcast_char, to_native, isdense, isshape,
ImportError: cannot import name 'IndexMixin' from 'scipy.sparse.sputils' (/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py)
>>>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bart I have managed to solve all the error codes. This is how I did it.

The install errors `error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'`, `Failed building wheel for py-postgresql` and `Failed to build qubit py-postgresql` were all solved by installing `wheel`, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci). In short I just ran

```
python3.7 -m pip install wheel
python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall qutip
```

The issue `ImportError: cannot import name 'IndexMixin' from 'scipy.sparse.sputils' (/home/kajsa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py)` is due to changes in the scipy package in the latest version. According to [this discussion](https://github.com/theislab/anndata/issues/146) it is not just a move but a change to the package so I had to install an older version of scipy. This was done by running these commands.

```
python3.7 -m pip uninstall scipy
python3.7 -m pip install scipy<1.3.0
```

Finally, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` was solved by following [this answer, and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36232975/4774022). By running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

**Note:** If you find that you get an error like

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'RECORD'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

You can solve it either, I assume, by adding the `--user` flag or, as I did, by running it as root with `sudo -H`, e.g.

```
sudo -H python3.7 -m pip install 'scipy<1.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

you may need to install/reinstall `wheel` pip package, or see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci

Comment: Thank you, that solved the install issue with the `bdist_wheel`. However the errors when trying to `import qutip` are still there.

Comment: reinstall qutip maybe? with `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>`. or `pip install --ignore-installed <package>` to ignore the installed packages (reinstalling instead). remember to specify python3.7 pip, as it may be using pip for default Os python.

Comment: for error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` it may work to reinstall `python3-apt` first. The error is primarily because of library `apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` not being present in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but how do I install apt for python3.7? Using `apt-get install python3.7-apt` doesn't find the package and `apt-get install python3-apt` tells me I've already got the newest version.

Comment: remove and install again should do the trick

Comment: What I meant is that python3 and python3.7 are different packages. python3 refers to python 3.6.8 where as python3.7 refers to python 3.7.3. Sadly due to other reasons I need to use 3.7 and can not use 3.6.8 instead.

Comment: The package is called `python3-apt`, there's no packate `python3.7-apt`

Comment: as well as have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg/36232975#36232975

Comment: Thanks, that solved the `apt_pkg` bit. Now it's just the `IndexMixin` not being found.

Comment: @Kajsa, you may have to install a lower/higher version of python package scipy to solve the issue, the world wide web is full of similar issues described.

Comment: Thank you so much. It imports now so it should be working.